# Removing the big title atop of a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint

I am wondering how can I get rid of the header based on the file name in SharePoint 2013. It really ruins the whole layout after moving to SharePoint 2013...

The Actual thing I want to remove:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0lRU.png

Comment: install firefox, run f12 console and play with css styles, it can teach you something about it. @Godwin posted proper answer for that but you can play much more with css with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1 (Works for all pages , however your **site will not have a Title**, the links will be not be having user friendly name in site navigation ! ) - Personally not recommended

1. Navigate to Site Settings.
2. Under Look and Feel , click on the link
   *Title , description and logo*.
3. Make the Title Empty, Click ok .This will essentially make your site Title empty.

Approach 2 ( Works on only the page you want the title to be hidden)

1. Edit the page
2. Add a Content Editor Webpart / Script Editor Webpart
3. Add the following code inside webpart

```css
< style>
    #DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
    display: none;
    }
    < /style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines in page layout just above Publishing:EditModePanel tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidePageTitle() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('pageContentTitle');
    elem.style.display = 'none';
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hidePageTitle"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open SharePoint Management Shell and run the following commands :

```
$webApp = get-spwebApplication "http://spwebappurl"
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class='ms-core-brandingText'>My Intranet Title</div>"
$webApp.Update()
```

Answer (score -4):

Using Below CSS Code You can remove Page or site tile Title.

## pageTitle

```css
 < style type="text/css">  
  
{  
display:none;  
}  
</style>
```

Comment: This is missing the selector.

Comment: Selector is missing from your Code.